# How to add website adds in Webview (Android)?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, ads

I have a webview, which shows the html content of a website's page.
However, I have the need to show the ads loaded in the main website in my webview.
How can I achieve it using a Webview?

Thank you in advance, and that's the code of my webview:

```
content = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.post_webView);
    content.setInitialScale(300);
    content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    content.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    content.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    content.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    content.loadData(mapContent.get("rendered").toString(),"text/html","UTF-8");
    content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<html><head><style>img{max-width: "+   (int)((display.getWidth())*30.0/100.0)+"px; max-height: "+(int)((display.getHeight())*70.0/100.0)+"px; width:auto; height: auto;  display: block; margin-top: 3px ; margin-left: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 4px; } </style>" +
                    "<style>@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf\")}</style>"+
                    "<style>body{font-family: 'MyFont'; }</style>" +
                    "<style>figure{max-width: "+ (int)((display.getWidth())*30.0/100.0) +"px; max-height: "+(int)((display.getHeight())*70.0/100.0)+"px; width:auto; height: auto;  display: block; margin-top: 3px ; margin-left: 0px !important; margin-bottom: 4px; } </style>"+
                    "<style>iframe{max-width: 100%; width:auto; height: auto;  display: block; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 2px; margin-bottom: 4px; width: 80%;}</style></head><body>" +
                    mapContent.get("rendered").toString() +
                    "</body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: why you need to add? your website will hand it....

Comment: I need it because i'm developing the mobile app for the website: i don't know if the ads in the mobile site will be triggered if the user is seeing the website page in the app, so I want to show them directly in the app!